# How do i add a button on top of a UITabbar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I'm looking for a way to add a button on top of the current layout of a UITabbar.

Is it possible to create a custom frame for the UITabbar?

any advice would help

[image: Rough mock-up of what i mean]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This project might help you ->

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/center-button-in-tab-bar